# How to use a template while creating an index with Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an index which is going to have a common structure every time it'll be recreated.
I've created a template on ES and want to use it while creating and populating the index via Java program.
How can an index template be used while creating an index from Java API.

Index template

```
PUT _template/quick-search
{
  "index_patterns": ["quick-search*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {

    "item" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "description" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've added an index template, if you now try to save a document on an index that does not exist and it has a name that will match the pattern that you provided in the template `"index_patterns": ["quick-search*"]`, elasticsearch will automatically create the mapping as per the template instead of creating a mapping based on your input.

Moreover if you try to create a new index and try to set the mapping (again that matches the pattern), the template acts as the default. So for a new index, you can set the type as `keyword` for `item`. This will override the default of `long` of the template, but the other settings will be taken from the template and will be present as well.

In order to test go to kibana and set your template

```
PUT _template/quick-search
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "quick-search*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "item": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then try to create a new index, but item needs to be a keyword

```
PUT quick-search-item-keyword
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "item": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": true
      }
    }
  }
}

GET quick-search-item-keyword/_mapping
```

And now just save a document in an index that doesn't exist

```
POST quick-search-test-id/_doc/
{
  "id": "test"
}

GET quick-search-test-id/_mapping
```

Try to save the same document in an index that doesn't exist and doesn't match the index pattern of your template

```
POST test/_doc/
{
  "id": "test"
}

GET test/_mapping
```

There is nothing different if you use the java client. The same will apply

Comment: I did but it doesn't register my vote for resolution. Shows following message :"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Thank you for trying to upvote. Upvoting is different than marking the answer. You tick the answer in order to mark resolution.